# Imaginary quadratic extensions in characteristic 2

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields, local-field, function-fields

Let $\mathbb{F}_q$ be finite field with characteristic 2 and consider the polynomial ring $A=\mathbb{F}_q[T]$. Denote $F=\mathbb{F}_q(T)$.

Let $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c\in A[x]$ be irreducible. I'm trying to prove that if $\deg(a)+\deg(c)$ is odd, then the splitting field $K$ of $f(x)$ is imaginary, i.e. $f(x)$ remains irreducible over the completion $F_\infty$. I've done a few examples, but I'm not really seeing a pattern that would help me prove this. Any hints?

Comment: Does this hold? I may have misunderstood the meaning of $F_\infty$ (I guess this is the completion w.r.t. the infinite place), so let's get synchronized. The polynomial
$$f(x)=x^2+Tx+T$$ is irreducible (Eisenstein with $p=T$). Dividing $f(x)=0$ by $T^2$ gives a new equation in terms of $u=x/T$, $u^2+u=1/T$. And this has its roots in $F_\infty$, namely the series
$$u=T^{-1}+T^{-2}+T^{-4}+T^{-8}+\cdots=\sum_iT^{-2^i}\in F_{\infty}$$ with $u+1$ being the other zero.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I believe you've found a counterexample. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yeah. Do observe that this technique does not work with $f(x)=x^2+Tx+T^3$, leading to $u^2+u=T$. The pole order (at $T=\infty$) of the left hand side is even for any power series $u$, but the right hand side has a pole of order one $\implies$ remains irreducible. May be this idea works in the instances you are really interested in?